# LOCALAPPDATA not found in mavproxy.py

Tags: service, mavros, bash, px4, mavlink

I have the following file `/home/pi/mavproxy.sh` which forwards the flight controller telemetry data using [mavproxy](https://ardupilot.org/mavproxy/docs/getting_started/download_and_installation.html)  to GCS(Ground Control Station)

```bash
#!/bin/bash
mavproxy.py --master=/home/pi/ttyUSB0 --baudrate 57600 --out=udp:192.168.10.12:14550
```

to automate this I write a linux services `mavproxy.services`

```
[Unit]
Description=Mavproxy service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/pi/mavproxy.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now the problem is when I execute `./mavproxy.sh` it work fine and forward telemetry data but when I reboot and do `mavproxy.service` Failed.

following is output of `journalctl -u mavproxy.service` which says KeyError: 'LOCALAPPDATA'

```
Mar 17 12:15:16 ubuntu mavproxy.sh[1076]:   File "/usr/local/bin/mavproxy.py", line 1489, in <module>
Mar 17 12:15:16 ubuntu mavproxy.sh[1076]:     start_script = mp_util.dot_mavproxy("mavinit.scr")
Mar 17 12:15:16 ubuntu mavproxy.sh[1076]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/MAVProxy/modules/lib/mp_util.py", line 285, in dot_mavproxy
Mar 17 12:15:16 ubuntu mavproxy.sh[1076]:     dir = os.path.join(os.environ['LOCALAPPDATA'], '.mavproxy')
Mar 17 12:15:16 ubuntu mavproxy.sh[1076]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
Mar 17 12:15:16 ubuntu mavproxy.sh[1076]:     raise KeyError(key) from None
Mar 17 12:15:16 ubuntu mavproxy.sh[1076]: KeyError: 'LOCALAPPDATA'
```